# Why aren't my custom Angular Material icons being registered?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, angular-material

Following docs:

https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#icon-sets

And this guide:

https://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started

I wrote this:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FeaturesModule } from './features/features.module';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatIconRegistry, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatIconModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FeaturesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
      domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./assets/icons/mdi.svg')
    );
  }
}
```

Then in the template `app.component.html`:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="android"></mat-icon>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and also I have set up `assets` in the `angular-cli.json`.

But when I load the page I get:

```
Error retrieving icon: Unable to find icon with the name "android"
```

the thing is, the `.svg` file is being loaded:

[image]

Maybe I'm missing something.

How to add correctly an Iconset in angular material 2?

Comment: It doesn't appear that material supports `glyph` tags. You need a nested `svg` icon set defined with `defs`.

Comment: Which section did you download `mdi.svg` from?

Comment: I've took the '.svg' from the  'materialdesign-webfont.zip'  fonts (it came with css, fonts and scss)

Comment: I'm in the same boat and I'm about to have a conniption! Did you ever get a solution? Is it simply that `glyphs` are not supported?